# C++ Getting handle from process without OpenProcess()

Tags: c++, handle

Hi i was wondering how could i get specific handle from process.

I mean i have dll what i inject into process for example. "example.exe" which has handles on various other processes and i would want to get handle to "exampleHandle.exe" which "example.exe" already has.

basically i would "steal" the handle, so getting the handle without opening new one.

This is how i did it with OpenProcess()

```
void ProcMem::Process(char* ProcessName)
{
    HANDLE hPID = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 ProcEntry;
    ProcEntry.dwSize = sizeof(ProcEntry);
    do
        if (!strcmp(ProcEntry.szExeFile, ProcessName))
        {
            dwPID = ProcEntry.th32ProcessID;
            CloseHandle(hPID);
            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPID);
            return;
        }
    while (Process32Next(hPID, &ProcEntry));

    cout << "\nCouldn't find process\n";
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You are asking for teleportation.  It is not a C++ feature.  Not an OS feature either.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do move the handle from one process to the other. You still have the issue of the handle values possibly being meaningful only within the process that originally opened them.

If you don't use `OpenProcess()`, you'll end up using `DuplicateHandle()`.

See the here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx